# PHP Session Not Loggin Out

Tags: php

Can somebody please help I don;t understand where I've gone wrong as I'm using the exact code in my original system (app.unknowen.dev) and it works fine.

The user signs in perfectly fine e.t.c then when it comes to logging out there seems to be an issue where its running this:...

```
<?php
// Before deleting session, first recreate session.
session_start();

// Destroy all session data and refresh.
session_destroy();
header("location: h.php");
```

....But, it doesnt log out it just continues to h.php (which is a js redirect system which goes back to the homepage).

can someone please help, or provide an explanation!
(test account user/pw: test123@example.com/Test123)
What its meant to be like = [app.unknowen.dev](https://app.unknowen.dev)

What I'm wanting but is playing up (Version 2 of my system) = [unknowen.dev/networks/v2](https://unknowen.dev/networks/v2)

Comment: A bit short on info here. So what determins a user is logged on in this system?

Comment: With the second one, you appear to be arbitrarily using the `www.unknowen.dev` subdomain in multiple places (for example your logout button links there), and then those requests are answered with redirects to the www-less version … Probably has something to do with it.

Comment: @CBroe yeah, thanks  mate a www-less version does work thank you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly also not too sure what you mean. When a user is logs in $_SESSION["id"] is set and proceeds to homepage (content changed to logged in ver. though)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to unset the $_SESSION array like in the Example #1 of the PHP docs

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: (however you tag people)... Thank you, but I replaced my logout.php file with said code and no luck